# Flashing lines of GridView in C # WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

I would like make a kind of signaling the red lines make it RED to white every a fiew moment with timer.until now i have made only the color RED without flash this is the code :

```
private void dataGridViewX1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
  {
   if (DateTime.Parse(dataGridViewX1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[8].Value.ToString()).AddMonths(-1).Month == DateTime.Now.Month)
                {
                    e.CellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;}}
```

until now I have only the color red  which appears

So I have tried write some code to get glow ( flashing my color Red with white)   in  event of Timer control timer_tick but its false i have only the same result

```
  private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int i = 0;
        while (i < dataGridViewX1.Rows.Count - 1)
        {
            if(
          dataGridViewX1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor == Color.Red)
            {

           dataGridViewX1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        if (dataGridViewX1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor == Color.Red)
        {
            dataGridViewX1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
            return;
        }
        if (dataGridViewX1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor == Color.White)
        {
            dataGridViewX1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            return;
        }
     }
```

Comment: Also I have always the same result only color RED Sorry :(

Comment: I made a stupid mistake there, now should work if I understood what do you want to achieve.

Comment: I have tried the new code but is also the same probleme i don't understand why

Comment: I just checked it, works like a charm. Are you sure the timer's property "Enabled" is set to true?

Comment: What i want is clear i think make color Red and white or RED and another color the importante thing is make Red dynamic not only color RED

Comment: Yes Enabled=True and what interval have you put ?

Comment: Does this code make your rows flash from red to white simultaneously?

Comment: I have the interval set to 100.

Comment: no is still always RED as before no i haven't color from Red to white

Comment: the objectif what i want is all the lines who have the color RED i want make him flash Color Red and white or Red and an other color just for making a beautiful view

Comment: Oh, yeah, forgot that you probably don't have the style set already, go to dataGridViewX1 properties, find RowsDefaultCellStyle, and change the BackColor to White.

Comment: Yes you are right and i change it and it works but not as i want the other line that i don't want to make him flash i want only the line who have a color RED that he should to flash not the other line

Comment: i think the first code that you are drop it who i want now the probleme is only in condition and thank you very mush

Comment: or i should change RowsDefaultCellStyle, and change the BackColor to Red ? and keeping the same final code

Comment: It's not this simple. The moment it becomes white it acts like any other white cell. It would require some more complicated code(remembering which one was red, and changing it back to white). I gave you enough hints, you can make it.

Comment: what i think is that    if (dataGridViewX1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor == Color.Red)
            {
                dataGridViewX1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
               return;
            }
            if (dataGridViewX1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor == Color.White)
            {
                dataGridViewX1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
                return;
            }

Comment: if color is white still white else change it To Red  i feel that i will crazy after solve it but is still Red as before

Comment: Then, for every red cell, it becomes white forever and ever.

Comment: Yes have you an other ways for Help i want solve it but i see is difficult

Comment: i am in progress i am near of the good result but i don't find any way